# Borrar una tabla con foreign key MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito darle un `DELETE FROM inventario` a la tabla inventario para que me borre el contenido, y luego de esto hacer un `INSERT INTO inventario SELECT * FROM inventario_temp` , pero, algunos productos ya los estoy usando en mi tabla factura, por lo que me da un error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`bdddistribuidoraard`.`ventas_auxiliar_ard`, CONSTRAINT
> `ventas_auxiliar_ard_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`VentaDetalle_IdProducto`)
> REFERENCES `inventario_ard` (`IdProducto`))

Quisiera ver algo simple, pero que no he podido hacer, que es borrar todo el contenido, y luego darle un insert desde la tabla temporal, bastante sencillo si, pero no ha funcionado, gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes desactivar [FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/foreign_key_checks).

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_de_la_tabla; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Recomiendo que antes de setear el flag nuevamente a 1, truncar todas las tablas relacionadas para no perder integridad de la data y mantener la lógica relacional del motor de base de datos.

Comment: Funcionó excelente aeportugal, gracias por tu apoyo! , ya pude hacer la operación que necesitaba, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

primero que todo, usar un DROP TABLE significa borrar toda la tabla con su estructura, para borrar el contenido y no la estructura se usa TRUNCATE, si mysql le restringe la eliminación es por que es un mecanismo para asegurar la integridad de los datos, ya que está amarrado a las facturas, una opción es hacer un borrado lógico, es decir, crar una columna y agregar un 1 o un 0 que se interpretará como borrado o no borrado, y en las consultas, en el WHERE se agrega esa validación, es la forma adecuada. Si se requiere la eliminación pura, se debe quitar el constraint de llave foranea y dejarla como una columna más, pero no se asegura la integridad de datos, ni la eliminación en cascada, entonces hay riesgos.

Comment: No era lo que buscaba David, pero tu explicación me parece excelente, ya que no sabía eso, gracias por tu apoyo!